# HERE maps marker with cursor pointer

Tags: javascript, here-api

How can i set the H.map.Marker object to show cursor as pointer? This can be done with H.map.DomMarker but not H.map.Marker

```
var svgMarkup = '<svg style="cursor:pointer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28px" height="36px">' +
  '<path d="M 19 31 C 19 32.7 16.3 34 13 34 C 9.7 34 7 32.7 7 31 C 7 29.3 9.7 28 13 28 C 16.3 28 19 29.3 19 31 Z" ' +
  'fill="#000" fill-opacity=".2"/><path d="M 13 0 C 9.5 0 6.3 1.3 3.8 3.8 C 1.4 7.8 0 9.4 0 12.8 C 0 16.3 1.4 19.5 ' +
  '3.8 21.9 L 13 31 L 22.2 21.9 C 24.6 19.5 25.9 16.3 25.9 12.8 C 25.9 9.4 24.6 6.1 22.1 3.8 C 19.7 1.3 16.5 0 13 0 Z"' +
  ' fill="#fff"/><path d="M 13 2.2 C 6 2.2 2.3 7.2 2.1 12.8 C 2.1 16.1 3.1 18.4 5.2 20.5 L 13 28.2 L 20.8 20.5 C 22.9 ' +
  '18.4 23.8 16.2 23.8 12.8 C 23.6 7.07 20 2.2 13 2.2 Z" fill="${COLOR}"/><text x="13" y="19" font-size="8pt" ' +
  'font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" fill="#fff">${TEXT}</text></svg>';

var icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup.replace('${COLOR}', colour != null ? colour : 'red').replace('${TEXT}', text != null ? text : 'P')),
  marker = new H.map.Marker(coords, { icon: icon });
```

If you hover to the marker, the cursor will still be the default. But if I use H.map.DomIcon with H.map.DomMarker, the cursor will become pointer

Comment: add some code so other can understand easily

Answer (score 9):

**Why does it happen ?**

In the case of an `H.map.DomMarker`, the marker is part of the DOM tree and can be styled like any other SVG element in the DOM.

However, in the case of an `H.map.Marker`, the SVG markup you defined is drawn in the *canvas*. This is why the `style="cursor: pointer"` rule has no effect.

**Can we style a marker in the canvas ?**

Yes we can.

You could add an event listener to each marker, to change the canvas cursor on 'pointerenter / pointerleave', however, to avoid adding too many 
listeners, we can add just one on the map object, and check the instance of the target element:

```
map.addEventListener('pointermove', function (event) {
  if (event.target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
    map.getViewPort().element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  } else {
    map.getViewPort().element.style.cursor = 'auto';
  }
}, false);
```